# How can I receive files using BlueDevil?

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth, transfer

I've just installed Lubuntu 20.04 on my ASUS Q551L and I have paired my phone with my laptop using the BlueDevil Wizard. When I try to send a file from my phone to my laptop I get a "sending failed" message on my phone. BlueDevil's *Bluetooth Send File Wizard* shows my phone. There is no panel icon (this would be a sign that the system tray application is active - correct?). I have not yet been able to find a *Personal File Sharing Preferences* file or application which I've read might be necessary for receiving files to function.

In *Discovery*, the description for *BlueDevil Wizard, BlueDevil Send File* and *KDE Plasma Desktop - Bluetooth* all say,

> It contains: . . .A system tray application from where all BlueDevil actions can be
>   done . . . . A daemon which listens to incoming requests, for
>   example to receive files . . .

Here are all the packages the have the word "blue" in them that come with Lubuntu 20.04[image: Muon Package Manager Screenshot]

It pairs devices OK, but I can't figure out how to receive files.  Also, I can't find the system tray application (is this also called a widget?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have investigated this extensively. It appears that either **BlueDevil** does not receive files or it does not receive files on ASUS computers. I installed **Blueman Bluetooth Manager** and its companion **Bluetooth Adapters**. I found them by searching "Blueman" in **Discover**.  **Blueman** can send and receive files and it has a very useful systray app accessible through right clicking its icon.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following;
[How to Enable and Configure Bluetooth in Ubuntu](https://quehow.com/how-to-enable-and-configure-bluetooth-in-ubuntu/3851.html)

This is for an early version (14.04) of Ubuntu - but it does tell you how to configure bluez

Comment: Thanks. I really want to know how to use BlueDevil to receive files. I've edited my question title to reflect this.